# Ionic2 - Google Maps Plugin, Error: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object])

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've installed the Google Maps plugin as instructed on the Ionic2 documentation :

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/

However, I am getting the below error

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object])

I ran on it on the web browser as well as on a native device, it does not work in all the cases.

Any idea about what's going on ?

Comment: A issue has been opened https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/950

Answer (score 0):

The plugin Google Maps for ionic only works on android and ios, not on web

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://github.com/danielsogl/awesome-cordova-plugins/issues/950#issuecomment-275658223) , it use the Native library. so, you need to run it Device.

Also ckeck the API_KEY and reinstall the plugin with the right one. following terminal command will help in reinstalling:

To remove -uninstall:
`ionic plugin remove cordova-plugin-googlemaps`

To Install again:
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"`.

Some days ago I had same problem and I solved by reinstalling the plugin. It worked like magic.